# What is constraint and effectivesize in structural holes?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, graph-theory, networks, social-network, social-science

Today, I spent the whole day trying to understand what structural holes in network means. More specifically I want to clarify what the two measurements *constraint* and *effective size* means? Is it good to have high constraint and high effective size.

Even though there are many resources online, none of them provides good examples and explanations on these two measurements.

I am happy to provide more details if needed.